# Application.Current.MainWindow.Show() for UWP

Tags: uwp

is there an equivalent in uwp to wpf's

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
```

I read an wpf tutorial and they used this to start the mainWindow and I Need this in uwp.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Window.Current.Activate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the scenario you are trying to accomplish to activate your app's main view from secondary. You can accomplish it like this:

```
int mainViewId;
await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
{
    mainViewId = ApplicationView.GetApplicationViewIdForWindow(CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow);
});
bool isShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(mainViewId);
```

Thanks!